# Civi Administer Tab issues

Tags: sysadmin

Anything I click on under administer tab goes to our home page...then list the administer topic?  So everything clicks to our home page then shows the topic?

Answer (score 1):

If you have recently moved from one location to other or DB.
please follow the link which should fix the issue

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location

Comment: in particular check urls in settings.php and civicrm.settings.php